# legend in Unequal upper and lower deviation in PGFplots error bar!

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I want to set different lower and upper deviations for error bars. It seems that `PGFplots` does not support unequal +,- error bar length. I have come up with a solution, that is to draw + and - error bars separately on the same axis.  In this case the legend does not show correctly.

Is there any other way to plot unequal error bars without having to re-plot the data?
Or is there anyway I can fix the legend probelm?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[error bars/.cd,
y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {
(0,0) +- (0.5,0.1)
(0.1,0.1) +- (0.05,0.2)
(0.2,0.2) +- (0,0.05)
(0.5,0.5) +- (0.1,0.2)
(1,1) +- (0.3,0.1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[mark=*,blue] plot[error bars/.cd,
y dir=plus,y explicit]
coordinates {
(0,0) +- (0.5,0.1)
(0.1,0.1) +- (0.05,0.2)
(0.2,0.2) +- (0,0.05)
(0.5,0.5) +- (0.1,0.2)
(1,1) +- (0.3,0.1)}; \addlegendentry{first plot}

\addplot[mark=*,blue] plot[error bars/.cd,
y dir=minus,y explicit]
coordinates {
(0,0) +- (0.5,0.2)
(0.1,0.1) +- (0.05,0.1)
(0.2,0.2) +- (0,0.1)
(0.5,0.5) +- (0.1,0.5)
(1,1) +- (0.3,0.4)}; 


\addplot[mark=x,red] plot[error bars/.cd,
y dir=plus,y explicit]
coordinates {
(1,0) +- (0.5,0.1)
(1.1,0.1) +- (0.05,0.2)
(1.2,0.2) +- (0,0.05)
(1.5,0.5) +- (0.1,0.2)
(2,1) +- (0.3,0.1)}; \addlegendentry{second plot}

\addplot[mark=none,red] plot[error bars/.cd,
y dir=minus,y explicit]
coordinates {
(1,0) +- (0.5,0.2)
(1.1,0.1) +- (0.05,0.1)
(1.2,0.2) +- (0,0.1)
(1.5,0.5) +- (0.1,0.5)
(2,1) +- (0.3,0.4)};



\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The upcoming version 1.9 of `pgfplots` comes with native support for asymmetric error bars. Sneak previews are available at http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/

Comment: \begin{axis}[ymax = 1.5] will fix your legend.

Comment: You will also need to reorder the plots.  \addlegendtry depends only on the order in which they occur, not where they occur.  So do all the positive error bars in order, then go back and do the negative error bars.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger, It is great! Though I couldn't find how to use asymmetric error bars in the `pgfplots` manual or the gallery. How to use asymmetric error bars in version 1.9 of `pgfplots`?

Comment: The section "Input Formats of Error Coordinates" covers contains examples for both `\addplot coordinates` (search for the syntax `-=` and `+=`) and `\addplot table`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use \drawplot option "forget plot" to keep the second plot (lower error bars) from appearing in the legend.

```
\addplot[mark=*,blue,forget plot] plot[error bars/.cd,
y dir=minus,y explicit]
coordinates {
(0,0) +- (0.5,0.2)
(0.1,0.1) +- (0.05,0.1)
(0.2,0.2) +- (0,0.1)
(0.5,0.5) +- (0.1,0.5)
(1,1) +- (0.3,0.4)};
```